# Convert time in Ruby (Sinatra Framework)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am really new to ruby.

Could i ask you to convert time in ruby, from this:

```
created_at = 2021-06-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

to unix time like this

```
1632928828
```

what i've tried to convert to unix time:

```
Time.parse(created_at).in_time_zone('Asia/Jakarta').beginning_of_day.to_i
```

but it returns nil.

Comment: Your code results in `1624554000` (as long as you have required `active_support/all`). Please describe your issue in more detail and show an example which allows us to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: sorry my bad, turns out `created_at` need to convert to string by added `to_s`, so it will be `created_at.to_s`

Comment: Seems like `created_at` is already a time-like object. Did you try `created_at.in_time_zone('Asia/Jakarta').beginning_of_day.to_i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out `created_at` need to convert to string by added `to_s`, so it will be `created_at.to_s`